# Имеет ли смысл использовать платформы аналогичные Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, мобильная-разработка

Есть платформы, аналогичные Google Play:
https://ilike.guru/nash-top/15-alternativ-play-market/
Имеет ли смысл использовать их вместе или вместо Play Market. И может ли Google заблокировать приложение, если оно размещено также на альтернативной платформе?
И, если смысл есть, какие аналоги использовать лучше?

Comment: Пока всё хорошо, но
есть некоторый шанс, что правительству США в какой-то момент станет не всё равно. И всех, кто сотрудничает с тер... каким-нибудь Хуавеем, предпишут забанить.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете разместить свои приложения на всех платформах . Никаких ограничений и исключений нет, ибо они не зависят друг от друга. Mi market, play market , app store - все эти платформы могут быть использованы для размещения вашего софта.
Чтобы было больше "народа" в вашем приложении, попробуйте выпустить их в play market и в каком-нибудь galaxy store (Из-за того, что там мало , кто выпускает приложения, велик шанс, что вас заметят )

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Google'у все равно где вы размещаете свои приложения.
Вместе имеет, вместо нет.
Samsung Galaxy Store, AppGallery (в меньшей степени).

Comment: Премного благодарен!